# about ros_humble msg file

Tags: c++, linux, ros2

I've already successfully build the project on the ros_galactic, and due to some other questions, I changed my ros version into humble and after which some questions occurs.
I get the following error:

```
In file included from /home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/msg/detail/footstep__functions.h:19,
                 from /home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/msg/detail/footstep__functions.c:4:
/home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/msg/detail/footstep__struct.h:76:10: fatal error: geometry_msgs/msg/detail/pose__struct.h: 没有那个文件或目录
   76 | #include "geometry_msgs/msg/detail/pose__struct.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/action/detail/exec_footsteps__struct.h:34,
                 from /home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/action/detail/exec_footsteps__functions.h:19,
                 from /home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/action/detail/exec_footsteps__functions.c:4:
/home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/msg/detail/footstep_array__struct.h:22:10: fatal error: std_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h: 没有那个文件或目录
   22 | #include "std_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/action/detail/plan_footsteps__struct.h:23,
                 from /home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/action/detail/plan_footsteps__functions.h:19,
                 from /home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/action/detail/plan_footsteps__functions.c:4:
/home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/msg/detail/footstep_array__struct.h:22:10: fatal error: std_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h: 没有那个文件或目录
   22 | #include "std_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/msg/detail/footstep_array__functions.h:19,
                 from /home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/msg/detail/footstep_array__functions.c:4:
/home/universe/Desktop/HRT/workspace/build/jsk_footstep_msgs/rosidl_generator_c/jsk_footstep_msgs/msg/detail/footstep_array__struct.h:22:10: fatal error: std_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h: 没有那个文件或目录
   22 | #include "std_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

And I checked my ros_humble source code. The right path I believe is `./install/std_msgs/msg` while my path is `./install/std_msgs/std_msgs/msg`. I guess that's the reason, but i don't know how to solve it. Could any body help me please.
By the way, the source code of std_msgs is under `~/ros2_humble/src/ros2/common_interfaces` and the whole ros2 project was cloned from the `github`.

I read the `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` and want to do something, but I find nothing wrong.

Comment: *"there is a same folder called std_msgs under the folder std_msgs...*" =  ` ./install/include/std_msgs/std_msgs` ?? Please simplify your descrriptions to the minimal. Good luck.

Comment: yes,that is what i mean, sry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

The folder std_msgs in your install folder is not the issue. std_msgs is a common package and should be installed with the humble version, so no need to clone it. You can verify the installation by calling `apt search ros std msgs`  in the Linux terminal.

Comment: yes, the . folder i refer is ros2_humble source code, and the std_msg is in it, clone i mean is the whole ros2_humble folder, and i am using the ubuntu20.04, so i can not get the humble by apt